# Find and Replace word in Visual Studio 2022, but maintain capital sensitivity

Tags: visual-studio-2022

Inside Visual Studio 20222 like would to replace e.g. workAddress to locationAddress in everyplace it occours within my .NET project. Some places it is written with capital like WorkAddress, hence I would like Visual Studios *find and replace* functionality to respect this, meaning non-capital workAddress should be replaced with non-capital locationAddress while capital WorkAddress should be replaced with capital LocationAddress

It seems to me that find and replace is capital insensitive. Is there someway to achieve this (even with regular expression)?

Comment: Just do 2 search&replaces.